# Differentiate Fourier cosine series

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $f(x)$ and $\frac{df}{dx}$ are piecewise smooth.
Prove that the Fourier cosine series of the continuous function $f(x)$ can be differentiated term by term. Can anyone help me with this question?

Comment: Does the continuous function mentioned in the second sentence have anything to do with $f$ or $f'$ from the first sentence?

Comment: I have edited my post

Answer (score 1):

Begin by expanding $f'$ into a Fourier sine series. (Note: if $f$ is an even function, then $f'$ is odd.) Consult your textbook / lecture notes/ online resources for the following: the Fourier series of a piecewise smooth function (such as  $f'$)  converges   uniformly. This allows us to integrate the series term by term. This results in cosine series for $f$, concluding the proof.

In a nutshell: it is easier to interchange integration and summation than differentiation and summation. This is why the proof works from $f'$ to $f$, not from $f$ to $f'$.